# What is the song that was playing in Code Geass R2 episode 10 at 11:50?

Tags: music, code-geass

What is the song that was playing at 11:50 in *Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion R2* episode 10?

Answer (score 1):

This track is not featured in either of the OSTs, after a long search I found this version:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nh8CS8PM7vk

or

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEK28DBU2_I

> The Unreleased Album is from people ripping music from the original
>   series and trying to reduce all of the foreground sound be using audio
>   subtraction and splicing from different uses in the series. It's a
>   massive effort and it's a real shame that we'll never get official
>   releases of a lot of Code Geass music, this one for certain really
>   should have gotten one.